# Открытие и скрытие блоков div

Tags: javascript

Каким образом можно исправить мелкий баг. Есть `js` код при помощи которого блок `div` открывается и закрываться. Но минус в том, что если я его дублирую и присвою другие селекторы, откроется только один из них. У меня три кнопки и три блока, но при клике на 2 из 3х кнопок ничего не происходит.

Так же, как сделать чтоб блок не просто появлялся, а выезжал сверху вниз ?

```
  window.onload= function() {
    document.getElementById('categories-pin').onclick = function() {
        openbox('categories-box', this);
        return false;
    };
};

    function openbox(id, toggler) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if(div.style.display == 'block') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
        toggler.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
        toggler.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    }
}
```

Comment: При  клонировании заново добавляйте обработчик событий. Клонированный объект ими не обладает

Answer (score -1):

Нашел еще следующий вариант, две кнопки заработали, но вот третья находится под предполагаемым открывающимся блоком и она не работает. Собственно код:

```
$('#sort-pin').html('<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

$('#sort-pin').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var
    $this = $(this),
    content = $('#sort-box');  

  if(!$this.hasClass('trigger')){
    $this.addClass('trigger');
    $this.html('<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

    content.slideDown();
  } else {
    $this.removeClass('trigger');
    $this.html('<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

    content.slideUp();
  }
});
```

Comment: SO - это база знаний по программированию в формате вопросов и ответов, а не хостинг блогов. Пожалуйста, приведите в порядок свой вопрос - удалите из него упоминания решенных проблем. И не задавайте вопросов под видом ответов.

Comment: Кстати, на сайте есть правило - "одна проблема - один вопрос".